# How to remove rows with duplicates in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates, multiple-columns

Having a dataframe which contains duplicate values in two columns (`A` and `B`):

```
A B
1 2
2 3
4 5
7 6
5 8
```

I want to remove duplicates so that only unique values remain:

```
A B
1 2
4 5
7 6
```

This command does not provide what I want:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'], keep='first')
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.stack().drop_duplicates().unstack().dropna().astype(int))
   A  B
0  1  2
2  4  5
3  7  6
```

Solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[~df.stack().duplicated().unstack().any(1)])
   A  B
0  1  2
2  4  5
3  7  6
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but if I want to do it only for particular columns it does not accept it. Like such a command doesnt work: df.stack().drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'C'], keep=False).unstack().dropna()

Comment: You need use subset of data - the simpliest is second solution `print (df[~df[['A','C']].stack().duplicated().unstack().any(1)])`